# How to add space between Devanagari and English in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file like so,

```
#greenऔर
<सेमीकोलन>
actionएक्शनmysql
admin2को
```

The expected output is,

```
#green और
< सेमीकोलन >
action एक्शन mysql
admin2 को
```

This is what I have tried to do so far, `sed 's/[अ-ह].*/ &/g' testfile` but the output that I am getting is like this,

```
#green और
< सेमीकोलन>
action एक्शनmysql
admin2 को
```

Is there anyway that it could be achieved using awk or sed to get the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.*` matches the entire remainder of the line, and renders the `g` flag useless. Assuming the character class is correct (sorry, I'm unfamiliar with Devanagari) you could use

```
sed 's/[अ-ह]\+/ & /g' testfile
```

though you'll probably end up with some extra spaces you'll want to remove.

```
sed 's/[अ-ह]\+/ &/g;
    s/^ //;s/ $//;s/  / /g' testfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Perl here:

```sh
perl -i -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/(?<=[अ-ह\p{M}])(?=[^अ-ह\p{M}])|(?<=[^अ-ह\p{M}])(?=[अ-ह])/ /g' filename
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VxdjHn/1). See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/bh6duw):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='#greenऔर
<सेमीकोलन>
actionएक्शनmysql
admin2को'
perl -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/(?<=[अ-ह\p{M}])(?=[^अ-ह\p{M}])|(?<=[^अ-ह\p{M}])(?=[अ-ह])/ /g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
#green और 
< सेमीकोलन >
action एक्शन mysql
admin2 को
```

The regex matches

- `(?<=[अ-ह\p{M}])(?=[^अ-ह\p{M}])` - a location between a Devanagari letter from the `[अ-ह]` range or a diacritic mark (`\p{M}`) and a char other than the Devanagari letter and a diacritic mark
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[^अ-ह\p{M}])(?=[अ-ह])` - a location between a char other than the Devanagari letter and a diacritic mark and a Devanagari letter or a diacritic mark.